# Getting sudden surge of "Unexpected exception"s calling the Microsoft Graph using GraphServiceClient

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the GraphServiceClient to call the Microsoft Graph successfully for months without any issue.  All of a sudden, I'm getting lots of service exceptions.

I know you're supposed to post the request ID on here, but I don't know how to obtain that when the whole request seems wrapped in a library method.  Either way, I need to find out why these exceptions are occurring.  Below is an example of code used that results in an exception, and the resulting stack trace as well as the time it occurred

```
// Get groups.
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage gusers =
    await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

GraphUsers.AddRange(gusers.CurrentPage);
while (gusers.NextPageRequest != null) {
    gusers = await gusers.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    GraphUsers.AddRange(gusers.CurrentPage);
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
2018-04-30 10:16:30.477
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: generalException  Message: Unexpected exception returned from the service.       
    at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__19.MoveNext()  
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown  ---     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
    at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__36.MoveNext()  
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
    at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__32`1.MoveNext()  
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
    at Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceUsersCollectionRequest.<GetAsync>d__4.MoveNext()  
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

Comment: I'd suggest using Fiddler to see exactly what is happening under the covers. Chances are there is some detail in the HTTP traffic that will signal what is happening. It's acting as if it didn't receive JSON back, an HTTP trace will show exactly what it did get back.